# Get Input from Bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap's modal control to create a popup form where a user can enter some input.

How do I go about getting the information from the form?  In the past when I am just using a form on a page, I have used the post variable to get user input - but would that apply in this case?

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: Is there anything specific you want to happen based on the input? It's no different if it's in a Bootstrap modal though. It's still a form and still submits the same

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX, that way you can submit the form, get a response and then decide whether or not to close the modal window.